# Deeper function call or same level call

Tags: function, call

I have a code that has complex function calls stack. I would like to refactor it which avoids calling function too deep. Currently, the function call stack looks like this:

```
function A () {
    a = 1
    return B(a)
}

function B (b) {
    return C(b+1)
}

function C (c) {
    return D(c+1)
}

function D (d) {
    return (d+1)
}
```

This is what I would like to re-write look like:

```
function A () {
    a = 1
    b = B(a)  // b -> 2
    c = C(b)  // c -> 3
    d = D(c)  // d -> 4
}
```

I'm not sure which one is a better solution. I feel like that calling B, C, D at the same level could make the code flow easier to be traced and easier to understand when the implementation in B, C, D getting more complicated. Is there any opinion of both benefits or drawbacks?

Thanks!

Comment: But in your first example, C returns c+2 and B returns b+3, while in your second example, they all return their parameter + 1. What is each method actually supposed to do? I think that's where you should find the answer. If it is just a series of calculations and you are thinking how to order them, I think the second option is much more clear and debuggeable. But it depends on whether or not each method is supposed to do something specific, you you are simply breaking down a calculation into abstract operations.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give a better example. Actually I want to indicate that the function B to D is handling function depends on the result of previous function.

Comment: Right, but does B have a meaning without C or D? Or are C and D something inherent to B's logic? Sometimes more than one approach is acceptable, you have to think which one more clearly reflects the logic, which is more understandable and maintainable. Maybe if you tell us what exactly they do, we might give you a more specific advice.

Comment: Still there, Veck?

Comment: I guess you are gone.

Comment: Hi, sorry for losing your response. I agree that it is based on the case those functions are. The problem I encountered is that a legacy code has chaining function calls like the first pattern (calling at the tail). All those functions are related to one flow but could be separated. The previous developer gave me a explanation that so that you can just call the top level function and make all things done.

Comment: Well, in case 2, you can still call one function, `A()`, and get all things done. What if you need to test or debug `B` alone, without calling `C` and `D`? What if `D` writes to the database? You will need to modify `B` or `C` to avoid that.

Comment: You mean that in case 1, it is difficult to do a unit test for each subroutine because they are not atomic?

Comment: Yes, because if you call `B`, all the following functions will be called. In case 2, you can just execute `B` alone. But again, it all depends on whether the following logic is really part or not of the preceding function. Does calling B without executing C and D make sense? If D closes a DB connection which B opened, maybe the first approach makes more sense (that would be a code smell though). Both approaches may make sense, it all depends on what they do.